# Keeping Select Value Wordpress Search Submit PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, select, search, dropdown

i've been at this for a couple of evening now, i've tried many different solutions and would rather keep it PHP rather than a jQuery solution or AJAX, here's my code, for some reason the Select Dropdown just won't keep it's value, any advice would be amazing. Thanks in advance.

```php
<?php
    $taxonomy = 'accommodation_area';
    $args = array( 
        'orderby'       => 'name', 
        'order'         => 'ASC',
        'hide_empty'    => true
    );      
    $tax_terms = get_terms( $taxonomy, $args );
?>      
<select name="<? echo $taxonomy ?>" id="<? echo $taxonomy ?>" class="postform">
    <option>Choose Area</option>
    <?php if($tax_terms): ?>
        <?php foreach ($tax_terms as $tax_term): ?>

<option value="<?php echo $tax_term->slug; ?>" <?php if ( isset( $_POST[ $taxonomy ] ) && ( $_POST[ $taxonomy ] == $tax_term->slug ) ) echo "selected";?>><?php echo $tax_term->name; ?></option>

        <?php endforeach; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>             
</select>
```

Comment: The form's `method` is probably GET and not POST? Try to replace `$_POST[ $taxonomy ]` with `$_GET[ $taxonomy ]`.

Comment: Sally, you are a legend! Thank You. As it's a comment rather than an Answer i'm not sure how to marked it Answered and close it...

Comment: Sorry about that. But you know, sometimes I doubt on my answers, so I chose "guessing" via the comment box. Nevertheless, I think all that really matters, is the problem got solved; right? =)

Comment: Yeah I know what you mean, really appreciate it though thanks.